I need to divide two columns sum() that require different a date range dimensions each
So I have two columns that I need to add up and divide. The problem is that each one requires a different date range dimension to sum and have the proper outcome, so the final division turns out correct.
First value:
It's just a sum of the total amount of appointments that a certain business got in a period. To properly sum this value I need to use a specific date range dimension, let's call it "date of creation", representing the exact date that the appointment was created and set.
Second value:
Pretty much the same thing that the first value, but in this case I need to sum up the income that each appoint generated to the business. The issue lies in the fact that I must sum the income based on another date range dimension. Let's call it, "sale closure date".
These two values, both income and appointment count, are on the same table, and on the same rows. So I can just make a graph with a calculated field that sums both values up and divides them. But the results are always off because it's only possible to assign one date range dimension for the whole calculation and to for each sum individually.
Formula for the new metric:
IF(Currency="Peso",(SUM(importe.)*Tasa de cambio) 
/(SUM(Agendamiento)+SUM(Venta_Ganada)),Importe Total 
/(SUM(Agendamiento)+SUM(Venta_Ganada) ))

Ignore the conditional IF, i'm only using it to implement currency options
I need to sum "importe" or income as I've previously stated based the date range dimension "sale closure date" and divide it by the sum of "Agendamiento" or appointments, which has to be added up using a different date range dimension called "date of creation".
I know this particular problem is caused by a very poor data structure, but I can't change that now, no matter how much I'd like.
I've never asked for help like this before so please, any idea on how to solve this or question that could help me explain my problem better, it's appreciated!
IF(Currency="Peso",(SUM(importe.)*Tasa de cambio) 
 /(SUM(Agendamiento)+SUM(Venta_Ganada)),Importe Total 
 /(SUM(Agendamiento)+SUM(Venta_Ganada) ))


You can utilize View's filters in defining the measure to address your issue. The following code demonstrates how you can define your LookML View to create two measures prefiltered on different date ranges. Liquid expressions in SQL parameters have been applied to provide filter values to the measures. The final measure computes the anticipated division of two sums.
view: view_name {
  sql_table_name: your_table_name ;;

  filter: creation_date_filter {
    type: date
    datatype: date
  }
  filter: closure_date_filter {
    type: date
    datatype: date
  }
  dimension: creation_date {
    type: date
    sql: ${TABLE}.creation_date;;
  }
  dimension: closure_date {
    type: date
    sql: ${TABLE}.closure_date;;
  }
  dimension: total_amount {
    type: number
    sql: ${TABLE}.total_amount;;
  }
  measure:  sum_creation_range {
    type: sum
    sql: CASE WHEN ${creation_date} between {% date_start creation_date_filter %}
          and {% date_end creation_date_filter %} THEN ${total_amount} END;;
  }
  measure:  sum_closure_range {
    type: sum
    sql: CASE WHEN ${closure_date} between {% date_start closure_date_filter %}
      and {% date_end closure_date_filter %} THEN ${total_amount} END;;
  }
  measure:  two_sum_division {
    type: number
    sql: ${sum_creation_range} / ${sum_closure_range};;
  }
}

